# how to keep length of ReqEX output stable in case of missing data, python2.7

Tags: python, regex

The following  regExp will match 3 words before and after **if they exist**

```
((?:\w+\s+){0,3}My_WORD_HERE(?:\s+\w+){0,3})
```

Output will be like this:

```
word1 word2 word3 My_WORD_HERE word1 word2 word3
```

or

`word1 word2 My_WORD_HERE word1` which leads to empty attributes.

How can we fill the missing words with a value such as '?' or any symbol?

The output would be like this

`word1 word2 ? My_WORD_HERE word1 ? ?`

I will be using this output for Weka ML

Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a replacement using a lambda:

```
import re

s = 'word1 word2 My_WORD_HERE word1'
word = 'My_WORD_HERE'
wnb = 3

pat = r'((?:\w+\s+){{0,{0}}}){1}((?:\s+\w+){{0,{0}}})'.format(wnb, word)

res = re.sub(pat, lambda m:
    m.group(1) +
    '? '*(wnb-len(m.group(1).split())) +
    word + m.group(2) +
    ' ?'*(wnb-len(m.group(2).split())), s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pure regex replacement solution but should do the trick:

```
import re

def replaceMissingWords(text, word, placeholder):
    match = re.match(r'(\w+)?\s*(\w+)?\s*(\w+)?({0})\s*(\w+)?\s*(\w+)?\s*(\w+)?$'.format(word), text)
    if match is None:
        return text
    return ' '.join(list(map(lambda x: x is None and placeholder or x, match.groups())))

print(replaceMissingWords('word1 word2 My_WORD_HERE word1', 'My_WORD_HERE', '?'))
// output: 'word1 word2 ? My_WORD_HERE word1 ? ?'
```

AFAIK the python regex engine does not support storing a multiple captured group on a stack, so we have to manually list out the capturing groups before and after.

<kbd>[Demo here](https://repl.it/CA5t)</kbd>